# How to get certain word from a column value

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring

```
Column A

/Site/Test1/mysite/Do?id=90
/Site/Test2/mysite/Done?id=10
/NewSite/Site/Test3/mysite/Do?id=90
/Site/Test3/mysite/Done?id=1901
```

What I am trying to do is get the `Test#` from each row as well as the # after the `=`.

I tried the following:

```
Select 
    SUBSTRING(Column A, CHARINDEX('/', Column A, 1) + 7, LEN(Column A)),
    SUBSTRING(Column A, CHARINDEX('=', Column A, 1) + 1, LEN(Column A)), 
    Column A
from
    Table1
```

I am able to get the # after the `=` but how can I get the `Test#` from each row.

UPDATE: `Test#` is an example, it can be anything in there. What is for certain is `Site` and `NewSite`.

UPDATE #2:

Updated Table:

```
Column A
/Site/My%20Web%20Site/mysite/Do?id=90
/Site/Test%20It%20Out/mysite/Do?id=101
/Site/Test1/dummy/Done?id=1000
/NewSite/Site/No%20Way/thesite/Do?id=909
```

Result:

```
Col1                Col2
My%20Web%20Site     90
Test%20It%20Out     101
Test1               1000
No%20Way            909
```

Comment: How do you know that `Site` or `mysite` are not the values of "test"?

Comment: So as long as we can get `Site` index + 1 and the next `/` index, the in between text is what I would like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    Col1 = substring(a
      , charindex('/Site/', a)+6
      , charindex('/', a,(charindex('/Site/', a)+6))-(charindex('/Site/', a)+6)
      ) 
  , Col2 = substring(a
      , charindex('=', a, 1) + 1
      , len(a))
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DEBB37305

returns:

```
+-----------------+------+
|      Col1       | Col2 |
+-----------------+------+
| My%20Web%20Site |   90 |
| Test%20It%20Out |  101 |
| Test1           | 1000 |
| No%20Way        |  909 |
+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: @Si8 Updated my answer

Comment: thank you but I get no result for the first column. I have updated my question to give you a more realistic scenario. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Weird, I am still getting a blank... Let me test it out further. :/

Comment: Sorry here we go: http://rextester.com/JAJ25817... This is giving me first column blank. Thank you.

Comment: @Si8 I fixed your rextester, refresh it.  the + (n) of the `charindex()` calls is = to the length of the pattern to index. Changing your code from `6` to `7` because of your change from `/Site/` to `/Sites/` corrected the issue.

Comment: Got it... Thank you :)

Comment: Happily accepted your answer and help... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select SUBSTRING(col,CHARINDEX('Test',col),5)
```

To test it with one example:

```
select SUBSTRING('/Site/Test1/mysite/Do?id=90',CHARINDEX('Test','/Site/Test1/mysite/Do?id=90'),5)
```